# Laravel dynamic queries on array of Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently trying to make a function that calls different scopeQueries such as `scopeByLocation()` or `scopeByPublished()` on models defined in an array. I've got the basics working through [this link][1]. However, when trying to access custom made query scopes that are defined in the corresponding model, I get the following error: `"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ForLocation($location)->get()"`.

What I want to achieve is a single method which loops through every model in the array of models and retrieves & calls the right scopeQuery on the model, something like this:

```
$modelElements = $model::{$queryScope}();
```

Where for example `$model = 'Modules\News\Models\Article'`

And `$queryScope` is a defined queryScope in the model itself. E.g. `scopeForLocation($location)`.

I've tested `$queryScope = 'all'` and I get a result just fine, however when I try to access a custom queryScope (`$queryScope = 'ForLocation($location)->get'`) that exists within for example the Location model, I get the following error: `"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ForLocation($location)->get()"`.

So this all happens in a foreach-loop where every model in my models-array gets called and then the corresponding queryScope gets called on the model.

Why does the `$queryScope = 'all'` method works on my dynamic models, but other scopes throw an error? I really hope someone could help me get into the right direction with this issue.

Thanks in advance,

J. Doe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've finally solved it the following way:

```
//array of models
public function models()
{
    return [
        'Modules\Website\Models\Article', 
         ...
        ];
}

//function that retrieves all elements for a model
public function getAllElementsForModel($model, $param)
{
    //instantiate model
    $model = new $model;

    //call queryScope
    //'queryScope' could be any queryScope that is defined within your model(s),
    //the parameters are needed for the associated queryScope
    $query = call_user_func_array([$model, 'queryScope'], [$param1, $param2]);

    $result = $query->get();

    //do stuff with your $result
}


//retrieves all 
public function all($param)
{
    //loop through the array of models
    foreach($this->models() as $model){

        $this->getAllElementsForModel($model, $param);
        //do stuff here...
    }
}
```

Sharing is caring!